# Can I use my localhost url as the canvas URL?

Tags: facebook

Can I use my localhost url http://localhost/mypage.php as the canvas url for facebook application?

Answer (score 5):

In the Facebook Integration section:

1. Configure the Canvas Page name, which is your application's URL on facebook.com.
2. Configure the Canvas URL, and point it to your webserver. If you're developing locally, you can use http://localhost:8080/. This will get used as the iframe src.

From : http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=120423

So it is possible.

Comment: Remember that your add and remove callback links won't work unless you use a location that Facebook can find such as a static ip address.

Answer (score 3):

For testing yes, and here I mean that **ONLY** you can interact with this page. Other users on other PCs can't access it.

I've written a tutorial about this [here](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/).